# How iptables keeps insertion and list consistent

Tags: iptables

I have a Golang project that automates the execution of the `iptables command` to modify the network, and at the same time needs to do checks to determine if it has been filled successfully.

I listed the rules via the `iptables -S` command, but there were some inconsistencies.

For examples:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $INET_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $INNET_IP
```

The corresponding `list` results are as follows

```
# iptables -t nat -S PREROUTING
-A PREROUTING -d $INET_IP/32 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $INNET_IP
```

The key difference is the **extra /32**, is there some parameter in `iptables` that simplifies the result of iptables -S to eliminate this type of difference? I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Internally it expects network addresses and stores them in the form address/netmask. /32 is the netmask of the single host; you only provided an IP without mask, which is permitted and treated as single host, so it added a single host mask /32 before adding a rule into kernel. This behaviour is documented.

During list operation you just saw its internal representation with netmask as it is stored in the kernel.

It is not the *key difference* in any way and you should just ignore it. This is not unique feature of iptables; some other firewalls from other systems look the same in this respect.